# Vue.js not working on fresh Laravel 5.8 project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, npm

I've created a new Laravel project with `laravel new test`. Then I've ran `npm install` and `npm run dev`. I changed the `welcome.blade.php` file to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" href="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <example-component></example-component>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and that's the only change I've made. However the page is blank, and the Vue devtools extensions on Chrome says "Vue.js not detected".

Since Laravel provides nearly out-of-the-box support for Vue, I can't see what's going wrong. The relevant files are below (untouched from Laravel's installation).

`/resources/js/app.js` (which compiles successfully with `npm run dev` to `/public/js/app.js`)

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

`/resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

`webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

`package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

Again, these are all simply as they get installed.

Any ideas? The blank page is successfully loading the compiled `app.js` file, which looks as it should (e.g. there's mentions of Vue and `example-component`).

Comment: Anything in your developer tools console?

Comment: Show me your console errors

Comment: @Jerodev Afraid not.

Comment: Odd to see script include using `{{ mix() }}`. Have you tried `{{ asset() }}` instead? I can only think it's including the one from `resources` rather than `public`.

Comment: @Lewis Thanks, it didn't fix it though. The correct app.js file is being loaded by Chrome, just (seemingly) not executed.

Comment: That's really odd. The only difference I can see between yours and mine is that I load app.js in the footer instead of the header.

Comment: What about `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `defer` your script

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

The reason is by doing this:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Javascript will be loaded as soon as it can and the element `#app` may not have been loaded yet. By defering, the JS will be executed once the document is loaded.

Alternatively, you can use jQuery to wait for the document to be loaded with `$(document).ready` (but don't use jQuery if you don't need it elsewhere)

Without jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/8068675

Edit: And as @swonder reminded me, you can also move the script at the bottom of the body. In which case it will be executed after the DOM has been fully loaded.

Comment: This, or stick the `<script>` at the bottom of your body tag. Simply #app has not been loaded by the time you're running your javascript.

Comment: This gives me a `syntax error, unexpected 'defer' `

Answer (score 0):

Try adding forward slash `'/'` while calling `app.js` file

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

The only reason is that the project is not getting proper `app.js` file's path. You can debug by pressing `ctrl+u` and check the path of the js file.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is not relevant. The **slash** is not mandatory since `mix` [handle that](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Mix.php#L24) and @user11632242 already said that the file was loaded by chrome but not executed

Answer (score 0):

Try `<script href="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` in the head of the document (like in app.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check your setup in below sequence

You have defined your application URL in .env file. For example, if you have setup your Laravel in `test` folder,

```
APP_URL=http://test.local/test/public/
```

**Important!** Use src in script tag, not href

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Check Your app.js is getting loaded correct by looking at developer's console.

Comment: `APP_URL` purpose is to be used as fallback to let know Laravel what the domain name is when he can't E.g.: a `Job` or a `Command`. Laravel already know the current `APP_URL` from the super global `$_SERVER` So it's not that will make it work.

Comment: The arguments of the ````asset```` function is relative to the ````APP_URL````. So, if you have installed Laravel in sub-folder and you are using ````asset```` function, you need to define ````APP_URL````.

Comment: Please, edit your answer that only concerns **sub folders**. This answer will not work for a proper laravel setup which is not the case for the original question.

Comment: I find one possible problem in OP's code, he is using href instead of src in his ````<script>```` tag. So, the app.js will not load at all.

Comment: Quote: *"The correct app.js file is being loaded by Chrome, just (seemingly) not executed. – user11632242 Jun 17 at 10:02"* It's not a problem relative to the path. It's a problem relative with **deferring**